# How to bind dynamic data in for loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have created the table in for loop to bind the images and after every 4 td i want to close the tr and its working fine. But im getting the last record only. please help me out.

```
    foreach($show_banners as $keys=>$values)
        {
            $id=$values['id'];
            $image_path=$values['image_path'];
            $width=$values['width'];
            $height=$values['height'];
            $html_table = '<table id="mt" width="100%" style="margin-left:20px;"><tr>';
                    for($i=1;$i<=$tc;$i++)
                    {
                     $html_table .="<td ><img class='center-block' src='$site_url$image_path' height='$width' width='$height'></td>";
                         if ($i % 4 == 0)
                            $html_table .= "</tr><tr>";     // Close and reopen the <tr> tag
                    }
            $html_table .='</tr></table>';
        }
```

Comment: I think your `$html_table = '<table id="mt" ...` code should go before the `foreach` loop. And `$html_table .='</tr></table>';` after the loop.

Comment: You should keep your table outside the foreach loop

Comment: i have tried your suggestion. The problem im facing is the record from database im getting either first record or last record and its running in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

See this.. it will give the output you want

```
$html_table = '<table id="mt" width="100%" style="margin-left:20px;"><tr>';
foreach($show_banners as $keys=>$values)
{
    $id=$values['id'];
    $image_path=$values['image_path'];
    $width=$values['width'];
    $height=$values['height'];
            for($i=1;$i<=$tc;$i++)
            {
             $html_table .="<td ><img class='center-block' src='$site_url$image_path' height='$width' width='$height'></td>";
                 if ($i % 4 == 0)
                    $html_table .= "</tr><tr>";     // Close and reopen the <tr> tag
            }
    $html_table .='</tr>';
}

$html_table.= "</table>";
echo $html_table;
```